# Order array of objects by nested attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I would like to be able to order an array by a nested object.
I have this array containing informations about objects on a timeline I would be able to order this by the `start` position that is defined inside nested arrays. I can get it iterate trough the array with `lines[0].events[0].start`

this is the array:

```
timelines = [
    {
    name: 'obj1',
        data: { id : 'obj1-guid' },
        lines: [{
          events: [{
            name: 'animation1',
            data : { id : 'animation1-guid' },
            start : 100,
            duration : 200
          }]
        }],
        video_url: 'url',
    },
    {
    name: 'obj2',
        data: { id : 'obj2-guid' },
        lines: [{
          events: [{
            name: 'animation1',
            data : { id : 'animation1-guid' },
            start : 4,
            duration : 200
          }]
        }],
        video_url: 'url',
    },
    {
    name: 'obj3',
        data: { id : 'obj3-guid' },
        lines: [{
          events: [{
            name: 'animation1',
            data : { id : 'animation1-guid' },
            start : 56,
            duration : 200
          }]
        }],
        video_url: 'url',
    },

];
```

I tried a function like this

```
function sorting(json_object, key_to_sort_by) {
          function sortByKey(a, b) {
              var x = a[key_to_sort_by];
              var y = b[key_to_sort_by];
              return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
          }
          json_object.sort(sortByKey);
        }

 timelines = sorting(timelines, 'lines[0].events[0].start');
```

but of course it's not working

Comment: You should return something from your `sorting` function in the first place...

Comment: ... and this `'lines[0].events[0].start'` is not a valid key.

Comment: @Redu I could return json_object?

Comment: Do you need it to sort just by `lines[].events[].start`??

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes, exactly

Comment: Then instead of passing the key, just do this: `var x = alines[0].events[0].start; y = b.lines[0].events[0].start;`.

Comment: `return json_object.sort(sortByKey);` after you fixed the sorting key arrangement in a dynamic fashion if it is not always the `start` property.

Comment: thanks @ibrahimmahrir and @Redu I used the regular `sort` as in the answer below. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a regular `sort`:

```js
timelines = [
    {
    name: 'obj1',
        data: { id : 'obj1-guid' },
        lines: [{
          events: [{
            name: 'animation1',
            data : { id : 'animation1-guid' },
            start : 100,
            duration : 200
          }]
        }],
        video_url: 'url',
    },
    {
    name: 'obj2',
        data: { id : 'obj2-guid' },
        lines: [{
          events: [{
            name: 'animation1',
            data : { id : 'animation1-guid' },
            start : 4,
            duration : 200
          }]
        }],
        video_url: 'url',
    },
    {
    name: 'obj3',
        data: { id : 'obj3-guid' },
        lines: [{
          events: [{
            name: 'animation1',
            data : { id : 'animation1-guid' },
            start : 56,
            duration : 200
          }]
        }],
        video_url: 'url',
    },

];

const r = timelines.sort((a,b) => a.lines[0].events[0].start - b.lines[0].events[0].start);

console.log(r)
```

Comment: This works perfectly!!! thank you so much. _I need to wait 3 minutes more to sign as correct answer._

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a custom sorting function to `[].sort`

For ASC sorting you can do

```
timelines.sort( function(a, b){ 
    return a.lines[0].events[0].start - b.lines[0].events[0].start
})
```

For DESC

```
timelines.sort( function(a, b){ 
    return b.lines[0].events[0].start - a.lines[0].events[0].start
})
```

You can read more about how the compare function is evaluated from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=control)

> If compareFunction is supplied, the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function. If a and b are two elements being compared, then:
>
> - If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b, i.e. a comes first.
> - If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.
> - compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.